# Calculate Value Dynamically

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, cte, recursive

I need to calculate a value by using it's previous value * ColumnX

Here is the formula:

**DividendReinvested = "Previous DividendReinvested" * (1+ValuationPercChange/100)**

Can I do this without a loop? CTE possible? Using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Here is sample data. I use RowNum as unique identifier to set current row from previous row.

[image]

Comment: if your only problem is the fact that InvestedValues is NULL initially, why not just add ISNULL - SELECT InvestedValue = (SELECT ISNULL(B.InvestedValue,1) * B.ColumnX FROM tbl B WHERE B.RowNum = tbl.RowNum -1)
FROM tbl

Comment: But InvestedValue does not have any value for any row. So it needs to be able to calculate its current value off its previous calculated value. So thinking recursive CTE possible for this?

Comment: I updated the table to initially set DividendReinvested column to NULL. Using SQL Server 2008R2

Answer (score 3):

I found this 'running totals' CTE example here (you should be able to adapt it to your needs). Note the MAXRECURSION
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310877/calculate-running-total-running-balance

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE (RowNum INT,Columnx INT)

INSERT INTO @Tbl (RowNum,Columnx)
VALUES (1,100)

INSERT INTO @Tbl (RowNum,Columnx)
VALUES (2,200)

INSERT INTO @Tbl (RowNum,Columnx)
VALUES (3,300)
;
WITH x
AS (
    SELECT RowNum
        ,Columnx
        ,RunningTotal = Columnx
    FROM @tbl
    WHERE RowNum = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT y.RowNum
        ,y.Columnx
        ,x.RunningTotal + y.Columnx
    FROM x
    INNER JOIN @tbl AS y ON y.RowNum = x.RowNum + 1
    )
SELECT RowNum
    ,columnx
    ,RunningTotal
FROM x
ORDER BY rownum
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this on the fly (every time a record is inserted) or as a one-time thing for already existing records (and retroactively)?

If you're doing it for all existing records, I'd say something like this may work, but you'll have to run it in a cursor or something so that it goes in order:

```
UPDATE [table_curr]
SET [table_curr].[DividendReinvested] = [table_prev].[DividendReinvested] * (1+([Table_Prev].[ValuationPercChange]/100))

FROM [table] AS [table_curr]
INNER JOIN [table] AS [table_prev]
    ON [table_curr].[RowNum]-1 = [table_prev].[RowNum]
WHERE [table_curr].[RowNum] <> 1
```

You'll need to do the first row yourself prior to running this to make sure that there is at least one good [DividendReinvested] value, but I think the rest will work.

Best analogy I can think of is it's the same as updating the [Manager_name] field in an employee table using an existing [Reports_To_Id] which correlates with the [Employee_ID].